# 0-dimensional Gorenstein local ring.

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Assume the following condition for the ring T = F_p[[X,S]]/I:

Condition 1. T is NOT a zero ring. 
Condition 2. I is generated by 3 elements of F_p[[X,S]], but NOT by 2 elements.

Then, is T a gorenstein local ring?

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $I=\langle X^2,XS, S^2\rangle$. Then $T$ is graded, $T=T_0\oplus T_1$, with $\dim_{\,\Bbb{F}_p}T_1=2$. But for a graded artinian  Gorenstein ring $T_0\oplus \ldots \oplus T_d$
one has $\dim T_d=1$ (and the pairing $T_p\times T_{d-p}\rightarrow T_d$ is perfect).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @abx's answer, these rings are not Gorenstein.

E. Kunz, Almost complete intersections are not Gorenstein, J. Alg. 28 (1974), 111–-115.